# PHP Cronjob on Docker

Tags: docker, nginx, cron, docker-compose, php-7

I'm on docker-compose v3, I've 3 containers: mariaDB, Nginx and PHP7-FPM. Where have I to install crontab for executing PHP scripts periodically? How can I use PHP bin from Nginx container for example? Should I create a dedicated container?

Answer (score 1):

Cron isn't running in your container. You'll actually have to create the cronjob on the host using the docker exec functionality

`docker exec <container name> <command>`

Then just schedule it on whatever timer you want in the host. For example

`* * * * * root docker exec myContainer /root/dothings.sh`

If you're running a Swarm cluster, you'd have to locate the host the container runs on first, and then execute it there.

Comment: The other thing you could do depends on the framework you're using. What I've done in the past is to use Laravel and Console commands. I would run a separate container that would execute a console command that is in a perpetual loop with a sleep operation.